# How can I capture hashtags on Twitter using Java?

Tags: java, api, twitter, hashtag, http-streaming

Using the Twitter Java API, how can I listen for all tweets containing an arbitrary hashtag like "#Yosemite" or "#Scubadiving"? I know twitter exposes an Atom API over http, but we don't want to poll for data, we want to be notified in real-time when the hashtags are used in tweets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twitter does in fact offer a push APi to listen to hashtags. It's called the [Twitter Streaming API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592259/how-to-build-a-streaming-api-in-java). Your currently able to listen to 400 keywords and hashtags in this case.

Edit: integrate streaming API with Java

http://awalkingcity.com/blog/2009/06/22/using-java-with-the-twitter-streaming-api/

Comment: Ok, thanks for the education. I assumed that the management of a set of persistent connections would be outside of the core business of Twitter. After skimming through their documentation, it does seem that they've been able to provide this capability, but in a limited, possibly monetized, fashion.

Answer (score -1):

I'm willing to bet that Twitter does not expose a 'push' model for search results. I've seen several pieces of client software that make it look like you're getting real-time search results, but they're really just polling at allowed rates through the search API.

Comment: You know, I was thinking that may be the case, I've got the Twitter ipad app and, yes, it does appear to capture tweets in real time, but it could very well use polling. So, in that case, I'm back to the http/atom api, right? Do you know what are the allowable poll rates?

Comment: IANA Twitter application developer, but I previously used TTYtter, a command-line Twitter client, for some time. As it executed it would occasionally display a message that the poll rate was changed(usually 150-300/hour). Therefore, I believe that Twitter has implemented dynamic poll rates in their API.